# proof that e.g. integers with addition is a group

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

How can we prove that a structure, such as integers with addition, is a group? I'm using group as an example of proving that a structure meets certain axioms, because the group axioms are relatively simple. I'm interested in general in how to prove that a particular structure meets a set of axioms.

I know how to prove for example for the integers with multiplication, that it is **not** a group (by showing that 0 has no inverse and therefore does not satisfy the 3rd group axiom), but proving that a structure **is** a group seems more difficult than proving that it is **not** a group.

Comment: take any arbitrary element of the set, show that it satisfies the axiom.

Comment: Reading your comment to the answer given I suggest to read from page 15 of https://books.google.co.za/books/about/Algebra.html?id=L6FENd8GHIUC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 5):

To show that the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$ together with usual addition form a group, you just need to check that the 4 properties* (or axioms, if you like) of a group are satisfied:

1. There exists an identity element in your group that fixes every element under the given binary operation.

Yes, the number $0$ is the identity since $0+k=k+0=k$,  $\forall k \in{\mathbb{Z}}$

2. Closure: given any two elements $a$ and $b$ in the set, we need to show that $a+b$ stays in the set.

Yes, given any two integers $a$ and $b$, their sum $a+b$ is again an integer.

3. Associativity of the given operation.

Yes, addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ is associative i.e. $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$

4. Existence of inverses: Given any element $a$ in the set, we need to find another element (call it "$a$ inverse") such that $a$ and its inverse commute and their operation together give the identity element.

Yes, given $a\in{\mathbb{Z}}$, then $-a$ is the inverse since $a+(-a) = (-a)+a=0$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ with addition satisfies 1-4 above, it is a group. Done.

*These 4 can be economized into just 3 properties, depending on which book you may be using.

In general, if you want to prove that some other structure $\textit{is}$ what you think it should be (e.g. a ring, a topological space, a $\sigma$-algebra etc.) then the usual method of proof is to simply show that it satisfies each of the defining properties. Just work through and check off a list, just as I've done above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This definitely helps. However, I'm still left with an unsatisfied feeling that you haven't completed the proof, since you've simply STATED that the integers satisfy these, without really showing that they are true for ALL integers. intuitively it seems obvious that they do, but theoretically, it could be that some special number such as 0 or pi or e^2 does not have an inverse over addition, or something like that. I understand that it would be absurd if they don't have an inverse, but is there a way to prove it, e.g. by induction?

Comment: There are certain properties of the integers that are generally taken as assumption such as well-ordering, division algorithm, Euclidean algorithm etc. You can think of property (3) above as coming from the fact that the integers are a subset of the real numbers, which are associative in both operations. But again, you'd be appealing to another list of properties. Where is the proof? Well...you can't prove everything. Some things need to be taken as definition.